# Checking IF NO Event in the Selected Month View of FullCalendar jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, callback, fullcalendar

I'm using [**full calendar**](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) and have it displayed on month view. I have buttons to toggle between months.

Now, I want to display a message saying "No events scheduled for the month." when there are no event objects for the month.

I'm thinking the [eventAfterAllRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/) would be the ideal callback to render/unhide this message. The only piece remaining is to check when events are being rendered or not. How do I check?

Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a work-around using elements rendered by the calendar. To any who needs it:

```
if ($('.fc-view-month').has('.fc-event').length === 0) {
    showEmptyCalendarMessage();
} else {
    hideEmptyCalendarMessage();
}
```

Comment: This is really useful.  I combined it with the latest Absolute Centering technique from Smashing Magazine to center a message on top of the area the calendar is located in.  I ended up removing the feature for the calendar, though, but the snippet may come in handy in the future!